# add newlines in .cshrc command output

Tags: freebsd, login, newlines

I'm trying to set up a "dynamic" motd for users when they log in on FreeBSD 10. I've got it set up so that it uses .cshrc and has a few commands to output some info. However one of those prints as a single line instead of adding newlines.

```
echo 'Uptime: '`uptime`
echo ''`who -H | awk '{print $0,"\n"}'`
```

The output of **who** comes out as a single line instead separated out. How can I accomplish it so that it adds a newline **\n** at the end of each line? I've tried a few alterations of **sed** as well, but it all comes up with the same result.

I am testing with tcsh.

Comment: why do you need the echo? Why not let `who -H | awk '{print $0, "\n"}'` do its job?

Comment: @1_CR you should post that as the answer.

Comment: @Patrick, I voted to close this question. Had this been SO I might have entertained your proposition ;-)

Comment: This should not be voted closed with "can't be reproduced". It can be reproduced, and the solution was found by someone other than the asker.

Comment: @Patrick, great point on command substitutions, retracting close vote if it allows me

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your approach.

The first is that you aren't quoting the output of your command substitutions. When you do this, the shell is wordsplitting the output on whitespace, and passing each word as separate arguments to `echo`. `echo` then outputs all its arguments on a single line.
The fix to this is to quote your command substitutions. For example:

```
echo "$(who -H | awk '{ print $0,"\n"}')"
```

The second issue is that you don't need the `echo` (or `awk`) at all. You're capturing the output of the command into a string, and then echoing it back out without any manipulation. Thus the `echo` serves no purpose.

Transform your mini-script into this:

```
echo "Uptime: $(uptime)"
who -H
```

*I stripped out the `awk` as well as it wasn't doing anything other than adding lines.*

There are other ways to do this as well:

```
echo -n "Uptime: "
uptime
who -H
```